# SMS Sending App / Pending Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have App which send SMS from Android . 
**Code 1**

```
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    Intent intent = new Intent("smsSend");
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, messageText, null, null);
    SendDbUserDao.getInstance(SmsSendIntentService.this).updateSendSMSStatus(intent.getExtras().get(Constants.id).toString(), Constants.sendStatus);
```

**Code 2** :

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    Intent intent = new Intent("smsSend");
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if(messageText.isEmpty()){
        SendDbUserDao.getInstance(SmsSendIntentService.this).updateSendSMSStatus(id, Constants.sendStatus);
    }else {
        System.out.println("SmsSendIntentService.sendSms()" + id); 
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, messageText, sentPI, null);
        }
```

Listener Class

```
public class SmsSendListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

String tag="SmsSendListener";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    switch (getResultCode()) {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            Log.i("Message Send Confirmation", intent.getExtras().get(Constants.id).toString());
            SendDbUserDao.getInstance(context).updateSendSMSStatus(intent.getExtras().get(Constants.id).toString(), Constants.sendStatus);
        }
        break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
        Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Sending Error :Generic failure" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
        Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Sending Error :No service" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
        Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Sending Error :Null PDU" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
        Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Sending Error :Radio off" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Question 1 : Logically code 1 and Code 2 are same ?? 
Question 2 : Output of both is very different Code 1 send sms to each number only once but code 2 send multiple times !!! Why ?

Comment: you code are very different. mostly because on actually uses the pending intent you create, but also because you don't understand what a pending intent does.

Comment: Can u please explain me the difference ..yes i don't clearly understand pending intent .. can u please explain with reference to this scenario...

Comment: a pendingintent is an intent that pends until it is triggered. triggering the intent will be done in the future, via the receiver.

Comment: which receiver ? (Take the scenario  of SMS)

Comment: the SmsSendListener extends BroadcastReceiver. that's the part that will receive the intent you put in the pendingIntent.